# How to get selected row in NSTableView? view(atColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:) return nil

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I have a `NSTableview` whose content is bound to `NSArrayController`.
And its `selectionIndexes` is bound to arrayController's `selectionIndexes`.
And this arrayController is bound to a `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Because arrayController's `selectsInsertedObjects` is true, so when I add an object to `NSManagedObjectContext`, `tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)` will be called. I set a breakpoint here and debug in console (I set tableview's delegate to itself):

```
(lldb) po selectedRow
11
(lldb) po selectedCell()
nil
(lldb) po numberOfColumns
2
(lldb) po numberOfRows
12
(lldb) po view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: false)
nil
(lldb) po view(atColumn: 0, row: selectedRow, makeIfNecessary: false)
nil
```

I can see serval rows in the tableview.

But why `po view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: false)` return nil?

How can I get the selected row in the delegate method `tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)` ?

Comment: The selected row is 11. The cell views are reused. The table view can create one view to draw all rows. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Willeke I want to get the selected row and change its property. Not create a new one.

Comment: Change the property in `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)`.

Comment: @Willeke I want to change when selecting specific row.

Comment: What do you want to change? A property of the view or a property of the data?

Comment: @Willeke I want to let a textField in the cell into editing mode and something else.

Comment: If you have one textfield in the cell, you can select the text field with `editColumn(_:row:with:select:)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the table view posts `NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` before updating its layout. So you're asking the table view for a subview before it has created the subview.

This is what the `makeIfNecessary` parameter is for. Try it this way:

```
po view(atColumn: 0, row: selectedRow, makeIfNecessary: true)
```

Comment: I don't want to manual create a row. I want to get the selected row that is automatically created.  Can you explain why `po view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: false) ` return nil ? There is exactly a  row in the tableview and that row is visible.

Comment: There are exactly 12 rows (not 1) according to the results of the debug command in above comments.